# How can I avoid writing long path names in package.json

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm using `mocha` for testing. I want to run test files in some specific order, so I have to provide paths of the files in script, but they are too long and I have many files. How can I resolve this?

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "new",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
     "test": "mocha /home/a/b/c/test/checklist/get.js /home/a/b/c/test/checklist/post.js",
     "start": "nodemon app.js"
   },
```

Comment: Use a [configuration file](https://mochajs.org/#configuring-mocha-nodejs) to pass the arguments.